# Why does ToList<Interface> not work for value types?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, covariance

If I implement an interface for a value type and try to cast it to a List of it's interface type, why does this result in an error whereas the reference type converts just fine?

This is the error:

> Cannot convert instance argument type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyValueType>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyInterfaceType>`

I have to explicitely use the `Cast<T>` method to convert it, why?
Since `IEnumerable` is a readonly enumeration through a collection, it doesn't make any sense to me that it cannot be cast directly.

Here's example code to demonstrate the issue:

```
    public interface I{}

    public class T : I{}

    public struct V: I{}

    public void test()
    {
        var listT = new List<T>();
        var listV = new List<V>();

        var listIT = listT.ToList<I>();     //OK
        var listIV = listV.ToList<I>();     //FAILS to compile, why?

        var listIV2 = listV.Cast<I>().ToList(); //OK

    }
```

Comment: Variance doesn't work for structs. Variance works for reference types because their representations (references/pointers) retain their bit patterns.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis should be contravariance, not variance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29

Comment: @Fals: Neither kind of variance works for value types.

Comment: You can read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: What exactly do you think a ToList<I> for a Struct should be anyways?  What exactly would the list contain?  Certainly not the original value types, and the interface isn't the struct so it has to be a reference type...  so you are, in effect forcing a boxing from a value type to a reference type by doing this.  Apart from the variance issues mentioned, this alone should throw up a lot of red flags in your mind about the issue that it can't be as simple as you think.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I was aware that a boxing would happen. This was on purpose, because I was doing some performance tests to compare the efficiency of code related to a previous question concerning `IEquatable<T>`. It's actually not clear to me, why I have to explicitely call the `.Cast<T>` and what is the actual difference to the direct `ToList<T>` call.

Comment: @Marwie A `Cast` operation *verifies* that all elements in a sequence can be successfully cast to the provided type and casts them. The `ToList` operation *enumerates* the sequence and returns a list from that enumeration. Each one has its own job. If (say) `ToList` did the job of both, it would have the performance overhead of both, which is undesirable for most other cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Variance (covariance or contravariance)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't work for value types, only reference types:

> Variance applies only to reference types; **if you specify a value type** for a variant type parameter, **that type parameter is invariant** for the resulting constructed type. *(MSDN)*

The values contained inside reference type variables are references (for example, addresses) and data addresses have the same size and are interpreted the same way, without any required change in their bit patterns.

In contrast, the values contained inside value type variables do not have the same size or the same semantics. Using them as reference types requires *boxing* and boxing requires type-specific instructions to be emitted by the compiler. It's not practical or efficient (sometimes maybe not even possible) for the compiler to emit boxing instructions for any possible kind of value type, therefore variance is disallowed altogether.

Basically, variance is practical thanks to the extra layer of indirection (the reference) from the variable to the actual data. Because value types lack that layer of indirection, they lack variance capabilities.

---

Combine the above with how LINQ operations work:

A `Cast` operation upcasts/boxes all elements (by accessing them through the non-generic `IEnumerable`, as you pointed out) and then verifies that all elements in a sequence can be successfully cast/unboxed to the provided type and then does exactly that. The `ToList` operation enumerates the sequence and returns a list from that enumeration.

Each one has its own job. If (say) `ToList` did the job of both, it would have the performance overhead of both, which is undesirable for most other cases.

Comment: Upvoted. Extra information: The `ToList<TSource>` extension is defined "on" `IEnumerable<TSource>` and it is `IEnumerable<out T>` which is covariant here. The asker could do `IEnumerable<I> listAsI = listT;` directly as well because of the same covariance, but that will not perform the (shallow) copy.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It works! But now I'm lost: why does it work when I assign it to `IEnumerable<I>` beforehand? If the covariance is working for assigning to `IEnumerable<I>`, why isn't it implicitely working for `.ToList<I>()` as well?

Comment: And additionaly I wonder why this actually works, considering what Theodoros Chatzigiannakis mentionend in his response (no variance for value types) I would have thought this is exactly not working in this case.

Comment: @Marwie It works for the reference type (`class`) only. Covariance works when both types (compile-time "from" and "to" types) are reference types.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen ahhhh - yes. Sorry I completely misunderstood that. So in fact the reason why it works for Referencetypes is the Covariance of `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<I>` and the reason why it works for ValueTypes with `.Cast<I>` is the fact that it is defined on the non generic `IEnumerable`  which doesn't require any variance at all. It converts the type by boxing each valuetype, which is inefficient but makes it possible to work around the invariant value types. Did I get that right? Would it be possible to integrate the second part about the cast into your answer to complete it?

Comment: Instead of `.Cast<I>()` you can also use `.Select(x => (I)x)` where you write the boxing conversion as `(I)x`. The latter method is an extension of the generic `IEnumerable<V>` interface. I am not sure which of these two will be faster.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It's not only a matter of speed: `Select(x => (T)x)` can handle some casts that `Cast<T>` won't handle. This is due to boxing in the latter, and the fact that a boxed struct can only be unboxed to itself, so any conversion casts will fail in `Cast` but will succeed in `Select`.